# Disable requests to Parse-server without Master Key

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to disable requests sent to Parse without a master key? I'd like to only access Parse through my custom backend and not give users direct access. Does public 'read' set on the User class mean that anyone can read the records in that class? If so, why is this a default - wouldn't that be against good security practices?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Public read means that anyone with your api key can read the user collection from your parse server. Api key is not the best approach to protect your app because anybody can know it by putting "sniffing" your network requests. 
In order to protect and provide access you can protect your objects with ACL's which allows you to create access for specific user (who is logged in) or to specific role. So you have couple of options:

1. Create a **master** user - each user must have username and password and when you create your parse objects make sure that only this specific user create/read/delete and update them. You must only to make sure that when you create an object you create ACL for this user so only this user will be able to modify and read the object. You can read more about parse-server security and ACL's in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#security
2. Using parse cloud code - In cloud code there is a nice feature of **useMasterKey** which provide full access to any object of parse-server so for each operation that you run (via JS SDK) you can also set the **useMasterKey** to **true** and then parse-server will ignore all the ACL's and will execute the query for you. The useMasterKey feature work only in cloud code context so it's safe. If you want to provide additional level of security you can run the cloud code function with your **master user (from section 1)** and check inside the cloud code for the user session so if the session is empty then you can return an error.

You can read more about cloud code in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/

This is the code which validate the user session:

```
if (!request.user || !request.user.get("sessionToken")) {
    response.error("only logged in users are allowed to use this service");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not quite clear on how to lock down Parse from responding to requests without master key? I'm planning on running my own backend and just access it via there. Would you recommend using cloud code over custom NodeJS backend?

Comment: Yes because it saves you a lot of setup time and it takes care of security and more

Comment: and how would I disable access for requests when not using master key?

Comment: When you create the objects you create also ACL's for them and automatically other clients will not be able to access them

Comment: Is it common for people to use Parse in conjunction with their backend? Where they have their own server but only use Parse for its simple user management?